# Command line incremental path completion with fzf or other similar utility

Tags: bash, unix, fzf

I am attempting to use fzf for a folder selection utility, and I only want it to show the directories int the currently selected directory. For example, with the directory structure

```
a/
|-1.txt
|-b/
| |-2.txt
| |-c/
| `-d/
`-e/
  |-3.txt
  |-f/
  `-g/
```

when my fzf query is `a/` i want the only options to be `a/b/` and `a/e/` and then when i change by query to either of those, my only options would be (`a/b/c/`, `a/b/d/`) and (`a/e/f/`, `a/e/g/`) respectively. I have been digging though the fzf man pages trying to find a way to change the input of the currently running fzf program or something like that but to no avail, maybe I am just missing something. Any ideas on what I am trying to do?

EDIT:

Something like this: https://youtu.be/jSmaHW3Pp44

Comment: You can pipe a find command into fzf to provide options: `find . -type d | fzf`

Answer (score 1):

[fzf-tab-completion](https://github.com/lincheney/fzf-tab-completion) might be what you want. From the README of that repo:

> Tab completion using fzf in zsh, bash, GNU readline apps (e.g. python, php -a etc.)
>
> This is distinct from fzf's own implementation for completion, in that it works with the existing completion mechanisms rather than creating a new mechanism.